# Azure cosmosDB incredibly poor performance

Tags: azure, database, mongodb

I have a mongoDB on Azure cosmos and the performance is horrible. I have below the time for a few requests that my app does on startup and as you can see Mlab is up to 150 times faster! I am using the free sandbox database on Mlab and the D1 shared plan on Azure. Is there something I can do about this?

```
Mlab

GET / 304                           10.854 ms

GET /ticker/advanced%20micro 304    62.278 ms

GET /bardata/ 304                   48.285 ms

POST /retrievevote 200              0.558 ms 

GET /getwatchlist 404               0.483 ms 


----------


Cosmos

GET / 304                          12.792 ms 

GET /ticker/advanced%20micro 304   4153.169 ms 

GET /bardata/ 304                  63.362 ms 

POST /retrievevote 200             84.527 ms 

GET /getwatchlist 404              1.484 ms
```

Comment: CosmosDB is not MongoDB, it's Microsoft's implementation of a "document database" that tries to be MongoDB-compatible. Thus, the same commands run on both databases could return entirely different results. Since CosmosDB is cloud-hosted, I'm not sure if there's anything you could do other than open a support ticket with Microsoft. The fact that Mlab works very well for you suggests that there's nothing wrong with your setup.

Comment: CosmosDB is horrible. I participated in the beta testing of the Mongo API when we were part of BizSpark. A few examples,
- Cursors don't work or at least not without a shadow collection they set up and charge you for.
- Extremely expensive (min. $20/mth per collection for 400RU) and understand 400RU can't handle a simple loop inserting records which will fail at some point in the loop.
- Not even 1000RU ($80/mth per collection) is not enough in any sort of low-med workload application.

Answer (score 1):

CosmosDB is rate limited (c.f. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput et. al.) so if you are doing some sort of large query and you have set your RU/s rate very low you will get astoundingly slow results from CosmosDB.